# fitting the total count on the count plot for every column using seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn

I am trying to fit the frequency of that no as a label on top of every bar, but failing to it. tried various things which were already asked in previous questions but dint help me.

data :

```
A   B   C   D
1   yes no  no 
2   no  no  no 
3   yes no  no 
4   no  no  yes
5   yes yes yes
6   yes yes no
7   no  yes no
```

Code :

```
data_new = df.loc[:,'B':].eq('yes').sum().reset_index(name='counts')
sns.barplot(x='index',
            y='counts'  , 
            data=)

labels = ["card", "location", "merchant", "transaction", "spendlimit"] # column names

for i in range(len(data_new)):
    plt.annotate(str(data_new[i]), xy=(n[i],data_new[i]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot index DataFrames like that.
You have to use `.loc()` or `.iloc()`.

Try instead:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4,3))
ax = sns.barplot(x='index',y='counts',data=data_new)

for i in range(len(data_new)): 
    ax.annotate(str(data_new.loc[i,'counts']), 
                xy=(i,data_new.loc[i,'counts']))
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: how do I add the plot size ?